# Javascript gives me a different value than I expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am writing some basic Javascript

```
// sample value of bigArrayOMG, real variable name!!
var bigArrayOMG = [3, 5, 7, 12, 13, 14, 20, 23, 29, 29, 102, 29, 39, 40, 56];

var bigArrayObject = function(bigArrayOMG) {
  bigArrayOMG = bigArrayOMG[3] + bigArrayOMG[9];
  return bigArrayOMG;
}

bigArrayObject(bigArrayOMG);
```

And am getting the result of 42 when I expected 36. Does anyone know why?

Comment: This is kind-of unclear code. Shadowing the outer variable with a function parameter, which you re-assign to a value of a different type... it took me a moment to be confident whether this would produce side effects. I suggest adding a couple distinct variable names.

Comment: I think you are right Jeremy Banks

Comment: the result should be 41, not 42

Comment: Lol. Sure, whatever you say webdeb *touches glasses*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand that `bigArrayOMG[3]` is pointing to the 4th index because array indexing starts at `0`.

`bigArrayOMG[3] + bigArrayOMG[9]`

is equivalent to:

12 + 29 = 41

Comment: OOOOoooohhhhhhhhhh. Makes so much sense now ;).

Comment: Glad to have been able to help.

Comment: If I have 42 kitties one kittie is not a kittie?

Comment: No the last kitty is a figment of your imagination.

Comment: bigArrayOMG never did what I wanted, even in the way you describe and even in a strictly coding sense :/

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript array indices begin at 0, so:

```
bigArrayOMG = [3, 5, 7, 12, 13, 14, 20, 23, 29, 29, 102, 29, 39, 40, 56];
bigArrayOMG[0] == 3
bigArrayOMG[3] == 12
bigArrayOMG[9] == 29
```

If you want your result to be 36, then use:

```
bigArrayOMG[2] + bigArrayOMG[8]
            ^                ^
            7                29
```

Comment: My array is RALLY BIG ::::::DDDDDD

Comment: If I just wanted my result to be 36 I'd use ```var tinyMind = 36;```